# Slope Tangent Similarity

Tags: calculus

at how many points do the tangents to the functions $y=3^x$ and $y=x^3$ have the same slope?

No idea how to approach this.

Comment: Hint: You can find the slope at any point x with the derivative. What happens if you set the derivatives equal to each other?

Comment: smart man you are brb doing it

Comment: Ok so differentiating it I get.... 3^x(ln(3)) = 3x^2  but how do I solve for x?

Comment: Not sure, but wolfram alpha can come in handy. Type this in the search box: 3^x*log(3) = 3x^2

Comment: that doesn't show any answers that make sense

Comment: Sorry; edited comment.

Comment: i know it doesnt show any results that make sense

Comment: oh never mind is the answer 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15371/discussion-between-beanshadow-and-panthy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We set the derivatives of the two functions equal to one another:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\;3^x=\frac{d}{dx}x^3$$

$$3^x\ln(3)=3x^2$$

By plotting, we see that the graphs of the derivatives intersect (at least) thrice, so they have at least 3 points where their tangents have the same slope (the points are: $x\approx-0.47$, $x\approx1.12$ and $x\approx2.77$).

Comment: Does not $d(x^3)/dx = 3x^2$?

Comment: Are you sure ? I find 3 intersections.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer.

Comment: OK, but ... we still disagree on the values ! One of us is probably wrong. The question is : who ? Cheers :)

Comment: Problem solved! Wolfram Alpha confused $log$ with $ln$. ;-)

Comment: Glad to hear ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The equation which makes the slopes equal is $$f(x)=3^x\log(3)-3x^2=0$$ This kind of equation cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions but solutions exist using Lambert function. In this particular case, the solutions are given by $$x_1=-\frac{2 W\left(\frac{\log ^{\frac{3}{2}}(3)}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)}{\log (3)} \simeq -0.467974$$ $$x_2=-\frac{2 W\left(-\frac{\log ^{\frac{3}{2}}(3)}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)}{\log (3)} \simeq 1.11887$$ $$x_3=-\frac{2 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log ^{\frac{3}{2}}(3)}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)}{\log (3)}\simeq 2.76762$$.

Even if this looks complex to you, let me underline that Lambert function is extremely useful. In particular, the solutions of any equation of the form $$a + b x+c \log(d x +e)=0$$ can be expressed using Lambert function (jus for memory, Lambert and Euler worked together this function which recently gained major interest in many practical areas of science and technology).

Answer (score 0):

Not to put too fine a point on it or be the bearer of evil tidings, but I believe tha Rainier van Es's answer is in error, and that there is at least one solution $x_1 < 0$, as argued below.  For $x > 0$, I'm not sure how many solutions there are, but I suspect it is $0, 1$ or $2$.  I don't have a complete answer quite yet, but consider:

$\dfrac{d(x^3)}{dx} = 3x^2, \; \text{not} \; 2x,\tag{0}$

and this leads to Rainier van Es's error.  Meanwhile, read this:

Let

$y_1(x) = 3^x = e^{(\ln 3)x} \tag{1}$

and

$y_2(x) = x^3; \tag{2}$

then

$y_1'(x) = \ln 3 e^{(\ln 3)x} \tag{3}$

and

$y_2'(x) = 3x^2. \tag{4}$

The graphs of $y_1'(x)$ and $y_2'(x)$ intersect at exactly one point $x_1 < 0$.  To see this, note that $y_2'(x)$ is a parabola, concave upward, with least value $0$, whereas $y_1'(x)$ is a monotonically increasing exponential curve with $y_1'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$ and $y_1'(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $y_1'(0) = \ln 3$; it is easy to see, by envisioning or drawing these graphs that there must be $x_1$ as stated.  Or if a more rigorous approach is needed, consider for example $f(x) = y_2'(x) - y_1'(x)$ on the set $\infty < x \le 0$; for sufficiently large negative $x_0$, $f(x_0) > 0$ while $f(0) = -\ln 3$; by the intermediate value theorem we must have $x_1$, $x_0 < x_1 < 0$ with $f(x_1) = 0$; furthermore $f'(x) = 6x - (\ln 3)^2 e^{(\ln 3)x} < 0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$ so $f(x)$ can have at most one zero $x_1$ for $x \le 0$.

For $x \in [0, \infty)$, the situation is more complicated and I don't have a complete solution at this point.  Maybe someone can chime in with the details of the case $x > 0$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I solved my error. Could you please edit your post now?

Comment: I'm weak on Lambert's $W$ function, I admit it.  And on Wolfram Alpha.  I was trying to figure out the case $x ,> 0$ with pencil, paper and my slide rule when the other two responders posted their now-in-agreement numerical answers.  Still, to my mind it would be nice to show there are $2$ positive solutions analytically, so maybe if.somone has a clever argument they will post it.  +1 to one and all and I bid you good night!

Comment: @Rainier van Es:  I hereby acknowledge that, having correctly differentiated $x^3$ in your edited answer, you have obtained numerically an result fully worthy of the "+1" I gave it.  I prefer not to edit my post but will be glad to add remarks in the comment stream pursuant to your request.

Comment: To Any Readers of This My Answer:   I wrote these words before Rainier van Es edited his post to correctly assert that $d(x^3)/dx = 3x^2$.  This explains my opening remarks.

Comment: @Rainier van Es:  added comments pursuant to your request.  Sincerely hope you find my "solution" accepable; if not, please let me know.  Regards and Cheers.